# Avoid automatic activation attempt in Windows 10 with builtin key

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, oem

I've bought a Dell XPS 15 with Windows 10 Pro. The key for activation seems to be manufactured into the BIOS/UEFI without the possibility for me to change this inbuilt key. Fine.

I decided to use a different laptop for my business operations. So I extracted this builtin key and used it for activation on the different laptop. Works as expected. I had to use telephone activation and this guy told me that now I activated my license twice. This means: I should not do it again otherwise I risk my license being blacklisted (or something).

Question: how do I install Windows 10 on the original bought Dell XPS 15 with a different Windows 10 Home key?

I am scared that if I install Windows 10 and boot it up, that it automatically tries to activate with the builtin Pro key before I have the chance to change it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how :

- Disconnect the Dell from the Internet and boot.
- Open an elevated Command Prompt (cmd)
- Type `slmgr.vbs /upk` to uninstall the current product key
- To install the new product key type :

  ```
    slmgr.vbs -ipk YOUR-PRODUCT-KEY
  ```
- Connect to the Internet and type `slmgr.vbs -ato` to activate the new product key.

After entering each command wait for a few seconds till the operation completes. Proceed further only when you get a pop-up notification for each command.

For more information see the article
[How to Use Slmgr to Change, Remove, or Extend Your Windows License](https://www.howtogeek.com/245445/how-to-use-slmgr-to-change-remove-or-extend-your-windows-license/).